# Search for element in large array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays: One generated from data extracted from a mySQL database with more than 100k elements. Each element is an associative array.

Now, I need to get each element from the second array and search for it (using certain keys to compare) in the first array and, if it doesn't exist, then add it.

Example:

```
$array1 = [
    [
        'uuid' => 001,
        'name' => 'Isaak',
        'surname' => 'Newton',
    ],
    [
        'uuid' => 002,
        'name' => 'George',
        'surname' => 'Washington',
    ],
    [
        'uuid' => 003,
        'name' => 'Harry',
        'surname' => 'Potter',
    ],
    [
        'uuid' => 004,
        'name' => 'John',
        'surname' => 'Doe',
    ],
    [
        'uuid' => 005,
        'name' => 'Jack',
        'surname' => 'Daniels',
    ],
    [
        'uuid' => 007,
        'name' => 'Donnie',
        'surname' => 'Trump',
    ],
    [
        'uuid' => 008,
        'name' => 'Donnie',
        'surname' => 'Trump',
    ]
];
```

Then, the second array

```
$array2 = [
    [
        'name' => 'Carl',
        'surname' => 'Sagan',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Giorgio',
        'surname' => 'Armani',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Harry',
        'surname' => 'Potter',
    ]
];
```

In this example Carl Sagan and Giorgio Armani will be added to $array1. Currently I'm looping $array1 looking if there is an element with the same name and surname. If it doesn't, then add it.

The problem is, with the number of values that I have, the script is taking more than 2 hours to finish.

The function that I'm using to check if the element already exists is this:

```
foreach ($array2 as $array2Element)
    foreach ($array1 as $array1Element) {
        if ($array1Element['name'] == $array2Element['name'] &&
            $array1Element['surname'] == $array2Element['surname']
        ) {
            // Both keys matched, the element already exists!
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this?

PS: The data comes as an array that I cannot control. I can add new keys if it helps, but I cannot change it another data structure.

Comment: are you getting array only...?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I should use a db query to search directly in the database. Think this is the fastest.

Comment: I mean to say you are getting array only form server or you wrote any query... I'm talking about the large array...

Comment: Sorry, not possible. I'm receiving an array and I don't have direct access to the database

Comment: I have only the array yes @GyandeepSharma. I have no direct access to the database

Comment: `2 hours` is really too worth time to execute any script can you share actual code and source of data how you insert/add ?

Comment: When working with real big data uses hashes for index and searching. Consider using a real database and let it doing what it is designed for: searching within large datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Index both your arrays to use the comparison criteria as key. E.g.:

   ```
   $array1 = [
       'Isaak|Newton' => [
           'uuid' => 001,
           'name' => 'Isaak',
           'surname' => 'Newton'
       ],
       ...
   ];
   ```

   Make sure you create a unique key, so two different names won't concatenate to the same key accidentally.
2. Add both arrays together:

   ```
   $array3 = $array1 + $array2;
   ```
3. Remove the keys again:

   ```
   $array3 = array_values($array3);
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Will it be possible to apply the same principle if there is another key? I mean search for (name AND surname) OR email? So, if the email matches, is because the record already exists in $array1

Comment: You would need to repeat this operation for each such condition. Which is still less expensive than repeatedly iterating over both arrays. As a rule of thumb: anything that is the key of an array can be found instantaneously. You could create a bunch of `['foo@example.com' => true]` arrays purely as index, and use those in a loop to check whether the email exists.